# Hyperledger Fabric SDK not starting TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to get a small golang application to connect to a hyperledger fabric network. The network is based on one of the official hyperledger-fabric samples, called 'first-network'. It is started by their 'byfn.sh' script and runs a **functioning** end-2-end test. The test executes commands directly using the 'cli' container that has all the valid crypto material.

I, however, try to do query or create a Tx using the `fabric-sdk-go`. I created a connection profile based on the official documentation and samples I found online.

```
sdk, err := fabsdk.New(config.FromFile("../integrity-network/connection-profile.yaml"))
...
clientChannelContext := sdk.ChannelContext("integrity-channel", fabsdk.WithUser("Admin@org1.example.com"), fabsdk.WithOrg("Org1"))
```

Reading the profile and creating the SDK instance works, however creation of the channel context fails and `peer0` of `org1` tells me: `first record does not look like a TLS handshake`

I'm a bit confused about the crypto material I have to provide in the connection profile, but based on examples online I think it should be correct:

```
x-type: "hlfv1"
description: "Connection profile for our integrity network."
version: "1.0"
client:
  organization: org1
  logging:
    level: debug
  cryptoconfig:
    path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/
  credentialStore:
    path: "/tmp/state-store"
    cryptoStore:
      path: /tmp/msp
  tlsCerts:
    systemCertPool: false
    client:
      key:
        path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key
      cert:
        path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt
channels:
    integrity-channel:
      orderers:
        - orderer.example.com
      peers:
        peer0.org1.example.com:
          endorsingPeer: true
          chaincodeQuery: true
          ledgerQuery: true
          eventSource: true
        peer1.org1.example.com:
          endorsingPeer: true
          chaincodeQuery: true
          ledgerQuery: true
          eventSource: true

organizations:
  OrdererOrg:
    mspid: OrdererOrg
    cryptoPath: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore/f6dc3f715ffd9547e5ff5e3e08d5ac17f1e2b09968d2daba9e7a9a4e374a2fb1_sk
    signedCert:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@example.com-cert.pem
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    cryptoPath: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/25117a9fcadf7b40ed7dcd29b7a478ca86728e564a8388aa889a5de71dec5df8_sk
    signedCert:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    users:
      Admin@org1.example.com:
        key:
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/25117a9fcadf7b40ed7dcd29b7a478ca86728e564a8388aa889a5de71dec5df8_sk
        cert: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
      User1@org1.example.com:
        key: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/e318dc3e94283337e3089673c8aca07ce0d6cc8ffdb03984ab2de11ec7ac11dd_sk
        cert: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem
  Org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    cryptoPath: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/078fca0bf56b77656f745e62100a1fd7d55f5d2c2925b6180daac49b67e64f0d_sk
    signedCert:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
    users:
      Admin@org2.example.com:
        key: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/078fca0bf56b77656f745e62100a1fd7d55f5d2c2925b6180daac49b67e64f0d_sk
        cert: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
      User1@org2.example.com:
        key: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/User1@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/3fee22d1537bc40b5e3d036919e3651976a92e42df5725983400a4012f5bc138_sk
        cert: 
          path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/User1@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem

orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com

peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  peer1.org1.example.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:8051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org1.example.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  peer0.org2.example.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:9051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
  peer1.org2.net.ink.tum.de:
    url: grpc://localhost:10051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org2.example.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../integrity-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
```

**Note:** for some reason I needed the `users` section, otherwise I would get a `user not found`. Most examples I found online did not include that section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `grpcs`  in your peer URLs:

```
peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7051
```

Comment: I now moved on to **TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate {"server": "PeerServer", "remote address": "172.20.0.1:41802"}
**
I'm not entirely sure if all the crypto files I provided in my config are correct.

Comment: Are you enabling client TLS on the server?  You might want to start with client TLS disabled on the server and make sure that everything else is working first.

Comment: TLS is enabled everywhere now. Seems like my problem is more related to my certificates being issued for peerX.orgY.example.com but I have to connect to them using localhost, as my network is running in Docker, but the Fabric SDK client is not. If I'm using the 'ssl-target-name-override' option properly and supply the peerX.orgY.example.com names, the fabric SDK client is unable to connect (reasonably so), if I'm rewriting to localhost, the certificate error arises.
If I want to disable SSL entirely, what else besides the grpc(s) change and CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED do I have to change?

Comment: What works if I'm using the override is the connection itself e. g. `DEBU Creating a secure connection to [grpcs://localhost:7051] with TLS HostOverride [peer0.org1.example.com]`. However, dynamic discovery later returns invalid connections
`DEBU Adding endpoint [peer1.org2.example.com:7051]
 DEBU Adding endpoint [peer0.org2.example.com:7051]
 DEBU Adding endpoint [peer1.org1.example.com:7051]
 DEBU Adding endpoint [peer0.org1.example.com:7051]`
So every host is attempted to be reached on port 7051, however, that is only valid inside docker, not from localhost, as the mapping is different

Comment: So `first-network` is basically set up to be entirely run within Docker containers and uses container names for the hostnames in all of the config.
In order to access things from the host system / outside the Docker network, you will need to modify the CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT env variable for each container (set in Docker Compose)  to specify the externally mapped port.  You can also switch to using `localhost` there as well but it might be easier to simply edit the hosts file on your host system and map all of the DNS names (e.g. peer1.org2.example.com) to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks for the advice and guidance. I opted to move my client into a container that is part of the network as well. This is the envisioned long-term solution anyway and solved the problem as I can rely on the real peerX.orgY.domainame hostnames and the certs match.

Comment: glad to hear it

Comment: @Roper - did you get this working in a container - any pointers for it?